# Caffeine cache refresh without downtime Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, caching, caffeine-cache

**Background**

I am working on a spring boot application. In this application, we have two different caffeine caches - dealDetailsCache and trackingDetailsCache.
Both of these caffeine caches have single keys, let us say, X and Y respectively. We just keep updating the values for the same keys while refreshing.

**Application Flow**

- In every 5 minutes, there is a scheduled job that runs.
- This job fetches some data from an external source and upon successful retrieval, updates the 2 caffeine caches (mentioned above)
- Currently, I am manually doing a `put` operation on each of the above caffeine caches to refresh the data for their respective keys:

  - `put(X, <<data>>)` for updating dealDetailsCache
  - `put(Y, <<data>>)` for updating trackingDetails
- Expected QPS is about 50 per second.

**What am I looking for**

- I am looking for a way to refresh the caffeine caches *(just like buildAsync)*
  such that it does not impact the application and there should be no
  downtime.
- If `put` is not the right way to do this, then would someone please
  suggest the right way to update the cache in such a way that there is
  absolutely no downtime.
- I read about CacheEvict, but there is a risk associated with it. It evicts and then refreshes. There could be some time between the two operations and any requests that come in during this period *(after eviction and before new data is loaded)* would fail.
- Ultimate aim is that the requests should always find the data, even if it is old for the time being. Would someone please suggest a clean mechanism for manual cache refreshes?

Comment: Caffeine is essentially a hash map under the hood, so I don't see any problem with using `put`.

Comment: But will the consecutive reads and writes not cause any issues? I mean at the time when it is being updated, the application would also be reading from it (as stated, it has high QPS). I hope that does not cause the application to abend with an exception.

Comment: A read is lock-free (per `ConcurrentHashMap`) so there should be no problem. The [read-write benchmark](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks#read-75--write-25) matches your case (reads and updates to hot entries).